# DataGridView showing in 1 column

Tags: powershell, datagridview, rows

I was wondering if someone was able to help, I have extracted some data into a Dataset within Powershell.

With the dataset I am trying to place this into a DataGridView.

Below is a snippet of code I currently have.

I set my table headers

```
for ($h 0; $h -lt $DataDocSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; $h++){
     $documentOutGrid.Columns[$h].HeaderText = $DataDocSet.Tables[0].Columns[$h].ColumnName
}
```

The above code works as I'd like it had each Column with the appropriate name. Next I try to fill the rows of data that I have.

```
> for($i = 0; $i -lt $DataDocSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; $i++){  
>  for($h = 0; $h -lt $DataDocSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; $h++){  
> $documentOutGrid.Rows.Add($DataDocSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i].$($DataDocSet.Tables[0].Columns[$h].ColumnName))
> } 
>}
```

The above code gets all the data I need put it places it all in the first column and doesn't iterate across the columns like i'd expect it too.

Is anyone able to see my mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right thing to do. Easier than I was thinking

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $DataDocSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; $i++){ 
 $dataoutgrid.rows.add($DataDocSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i].ItemArray)
}
```